# Can not remove AWS Amplify Auth

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, aws-amplify

I have a web app using the following amplify resources:
Auth
API
Function
Hosting

I have been having issues with the Auth service giving the following network error when going through the Auth0 flows:
error message in the headers:

`x-amzn-errormessage: IdentityPool 'us-east-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' not found.`

Error message in console:
`POST https://cognito-identity.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ 400`

So I am trying to completely remove the Auth section and try and build it again from scratch.

However, when I run:

`amplify remove auth`

it removes the Auth in my local code, but then won't allow me to "amplify push" or "amplify publish" because the auth service can not be found ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️ and I get this message:

`Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource auththisismyappg986421b An error occurred during the push operation: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource auththisismyappg986421b`

Anyone know how to solve this? or advice on how to get
AWS Amplify - React - React Router (using protected routes) to all play along nicely?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any other resources that depend on auth? (api, storage, etc.)
If you do, when you do remove auth you get this warning:

```
You have configured resources that might depend on this Cognito resource.  Updating this Cognito resource could have unintended side effects.
```

Judging from you message you might have an API that depends on your Auth. Look at amplify/api/YOURAPI/parameters.json, you should have

```
   {
      "AppSyncApiName": "YOURAPI",
      "AuthCognitoUserPoolId": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "auththisismyappg986421b",
          "Outputs.UserPoolId"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Therefore a dependency to your deleted auth still exists and Amplify does not like that.

What you can do is create your new auth from scratch, then you'll get a new userPoolID let's say auththisismyappgXXXXXXX and replace every instances of auththisismyappg986421b with auththisismyappgXXXXXXX.

Edit: by the way if anyone has a way to do it more cleanly through amplify CLI that would be nice :)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the reply. I did indeed have the API linked to the Auth, so that could have been the problem. 

I found that fo some reason the federated identity pool was missing and that's why the Auth wasn't working in the first place. 

I could not test your solution as I just basically rebuilt the whole backend from scratch. Was some good practice for me and quite quick with amplify.